# JSON print specific value in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print only project name from data which looks like this

```
[{'Project Name': 'ABC'}, {'Customer Name': None}, {'Customer Address': None}, {'Project Description': 'Industries Pvt limited'}]
```

with my Python Code

```
with open('project.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)

for p in data:
    if 'Project Name' in p:
        print(p)
#Here it prints {'Project Name': 'ABC'}
# Print each property of the object
for p in data:
  print(p['Project Name'])
```

It prints out the Project Name as ABC but gives a Key Error like this

```
KeyError: 'Project Name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Project Name": "ABC",
        "Customer Name": "None",
        "Customer Address": "None",
        "Project Description": "Industries Pvt limited"
    },
    {
        "Project Name": "QWERTY",
        "Customer Name": "None",
        "Customer Address": "None",
        "Project Description": "Some Text"
    }
]
```

And here's the python file:

```
import json

with open('my_json_file.json') as json_file:
    my_json = json.load(json_file)
    for data in my_json:
        print(data["Project Name"])
```

Output would look like this:

```
ABC
QWERTY
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well

Comment: That isn't the JSON posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if` statement to see if `p` has a `Project Name` before trying to print it.

Comment: That's what is in the JSON you posted; what were you expecting?

Comment: Scott I was expecting the output to be ABC, I did the mistake of inserting 'for' outside 'with' loop. Thanks for the help though. appreciate it :)

Comment: `print(p['Project Name'])` will *not* show `{'Project Name': 'ABC'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. You can check your JSON here: [json lint](https://jsonlint.com/?code=)

Use double quote marks for your JSON to make it valid.

```
[
{
    "Project Name": "ABC"
},
{
    "Customer Name": "None"
},
{
    "Customer Address": "None"
},
{
    "Project Description": "Industries Pvt limited"
}
]
```

I suggest use a JSON editor to compose your JSON: [json editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `for` to iterate the items because the key 'Project Name' doesn't exist at the later indies. Or you have to use `if` statement to judge if the key name exists.

Another suggestion is that the data you provided seems like a list of dict rather than common json. Why not use ast? Try the codes below:

```
import ast

txt = "[{'Project Name': 'ABC'}, {'Customer Name': None}, {'Customer Address': None}, {'Project Description': 'Industries Pvt limited'}]"
data = ast.literal_eval(txt)

print(data[0]['Project Name'])
```